# Java-style printing of `double` in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

Is there any combination of stream manipulators (or any other method in the standard C++) that would allow me to get the "right" number of digits when printing `double` in C++?

By the "right" number I mean the number of digits as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)):

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must be 0.

In a bit of a simplistic example, let's suppose that we have three `double` values: DD, D0 and D1. DD is the "middle", D1 has mantissa larger by 1, D0 smaller by 1.

When printed to some very large arbitrary precision, they produce the following values (the numbers in the example are completely off the wall):

```
D0 => 1.299999999701323987
DD => 1.300000000124034353
D1 => 1.300000000524034353
```

(EPSILON, the value of least significant bit of mantissa at 0 exponent, is ~ 0.0000000004)

In that case, the method above would produce

```
D0 => 1.2999999997
DD => 1.3
DD => 1.3000000005
```

Comment: Reading the description, perhaps you want to use [`std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) as the precision?

Comment: So basically you want to print a double with no trailing 0's, right?

Comment: You seem to want [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) (the overloads without `int precision` parameter), but the compiler support for it is very scarce.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I believe it is fully implemented in MSVS and has pretty impressive speed.

Comment: @NathanOliver For once MSVC implemented something faster than GCC/Clang. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know :) They seem to be taking language compliance and library compliance pretty serious these days.  I'm quite happy with the latest MSVS 2017.

Comment: @NathanOliver — it’s more complicated than no trailing zeros. It requires just enough significant digits to distinguish the value from the two adjacent values. The number of digits depends on the value being converted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars).

> value is converted to a string as if by `std::printf` in the default ("C") locale. The conversion specifier is `f` or `e` (resolving in favor of `f` in case of a tie), chosen according to the requirement for a shortest representation: the string representation consists of the smallest number of characters such that there is at least one digit before the radix point (if present) and parsing the representation using the corresponding `std::from_char`s function recovers value exactly. If there are several such representations, one with the smallest difference to value is chosen, resolving any remaining ties using rounding according to `std::round_to_nearest`.

It's a low-level function, so printing the result requires some work:

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BgVU1AnUNBMWRMXGJtvWNzbltwz1hfWUDCQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CYbbsgIDWgMAG6H2CYaAIKb27uYB0dOCgTEmKzXtw/3YQIexYTDCEDmfxMAHYrPc9vC9ugltF6HsLmJXgARPYaAB0XDMG0kh1h/zuCL2Jwae2iXioJgArBZ/MSGZiSX8KQAqD7oEAgIgAfSpxAUEFpVFINLpB0se3SAC9MKgqNLJWixHNcclPli9mB1gy3BoDRz7pyEbz%2BWgvEDDm57WrXg6jvrDW4GKaNqToZiOAtaJwGbw/BwtKRUJwHZZrPKlisXpseKQCJp/QsANYgMySXGSBks/xmBKSMz%2BfwaDYADn0nEkIbTEc4vAUIA0KbTCzgsBgiBQqBYyTocXIlDQg%2BH8WAXAJfDoBDirfFjeiYQaAE9OMnx2xBAB5Bi0Tdh3hYEFGcQn0j4L41C6YVtXzCqaq2tbhwGYQNX2h4aLEDcPCwLdeE%2BPAWBAhYqAMYAFAANTwTAAHc92SRgQJkQQRDEdgpEw%2BQlDURtdC4fRDGMaxrH0P9W0gBZUB1TJHwAWl5Q5MVMGNLDMDQ9mYgB1MRaD4/jn0%2BJg%2BLQ9BDEcZBmLiYgSAUFsv2qRxnAgVxRj8UiQimUpyj0VJ0nUrJPBaIyClM3oDIGUj2lMroRnM3J7NUjoGCcyYSn6eJ7ImbS9A%2BbobN8iQFgUeNVj0T5MDWHgAyDBsr0jDhVCrfxmJZPZgGQZA9hnXEzD2CBoysSwpVwQgSFlDZSL2DwJ3oYhaq4OZQM7BYEG%2BLB4nBUgszLXEGShBINjMBkGSrDQzCrSQNiSb961ICCGXbUNw1Sls2w7E8u17CAkCWAhkltUcIHHIdmr0TB8CIPz8Ow8Q8P4QRFBUdQryQgDkkg2sOGDUgNt4VK91tU6gRVPZ0sy7LcvywritKgcrriVr2t2rQ5i6nqBn6pbeFW9bGy22wdtTPbM2zfxcSrKENCLGbZrmkaiX%2BjZks25tMf9UhuygA6kEuydzuF66dnIwVPi8BgMznWgF1FShohXNdiGPbcB13AgDyPRsz3Iy9wxvNS8HvR9w2fV8F0bT9v3DX9/0AjB4tA4hwL%2B6CmFghDkNQ9DuF4V7hFEZ7pGD96iKvXQzDIowUEoirHdo/qGNMli2I2DjE4sHiRKEkSxIAyTbpkvA5IUpS%2BN5R32MdzjyosFT7FMlwGHcFydKCdvQpmB7jMKMyci7gfrP0sK3Jb2oAs7oL3MciZe8M/zukClfGiXuyIqi3CUy%2BV3EoBzmQc4GGsskSkDCMErpdluYSrKqi9iq%2B7WqlRrUZazYzAximsZxpgvVKBUw2BsIqGgoSSEkHTKsI0oRmChDWAmK0QBrSBiTbmrZ2x/15vzQ6IBjoQ1FijSc2Ygh3RIHoYOT1cLh1kJHT64ZvpMF%2BoHQ%2BgNgZNg4GDE6to9hQzPtlCW18IC3wzPfZGTU0bf1/p1Ug3VAF40PstIm6CUqYPJnIwaUJcQaGmtNBkoCGQIPgVwQI34OZqK5hwDqe0%2BYHUFv2KRZAKAXRIddC4yBkjJEFBcLgCRBQGAXB8QUqgWTy0VkuFWV5VzMHVhhHcjAdaHmPMbTA55gBG1PHgW8jhzaNitsgN8GE7aNkdgBdWQF3xuw9mwvgMF4KIRQmhUMyZqGh1ofhBhxEQAbDjhRLiNhk7wHooxAQj4AD0VoG7WCCQ%2BAgzdTYaS0rPXSPdx590siZTIa98jbKKBs5eth57T1Xqs45U9OiL0OXZIYZzh5BWuT5TZbVFjLGiqRWKB9/ocIwWlbKLAFCeLRP43EcyPgPxzpVChX9CT1Q/pOWqGxZGUwGtmBk/0VGoOJuomxZNsGdnsfAfBhCzquLFgMPpt1qoPXaThCQdC3qEUYbwZhrCEo/OPlwnhEN%2BGqjCRfQFwK/EJDBUwYJQJJGfyRSi/%2B8jcZ9WUYTbFViT54qwTzbGaKzBcGGgkHVM5JBjR1eWcxnBLGcNJjgrV34zBcqtXI%2B8opMggEkEAA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd>

```
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double val = 0.1234;
    
    char buf[64];
    *std::to_chars(buf, buf + sizeof buf, val).ptr = '\0';
    
    std::cout << buf << '\n';
}
```

This function needs an up-to-date standard library: GCC (libstdc++) 11 or newer, or Clang (libc++) 14 or newer (currently trunk). MSVC also supports it.

Answer (score -1):

Absent the [C++17 library function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370758/8586227) that isn’t implemented everywhere yet, you can just try precisions (with whatever equivalent of `%g`) until one rounds back exactly.  If you don’t care about subnormal numbers (where even two digits can be too many), start at 15 for IEEE 754 doubles; that never produces meaningless trailing digits.  You’ll never need to go past 17.